# How to build a multicriteria search form leading to faceted search

Tags: views, search

I have seen a Drupal site that looks like this and it has an interesting [search form](http://nu.pe/3) that has several options for each field to search. This form is filled out (and can be expanded or contracted) and then goes to a faceted search. Unfortunately there is very little information on building advanced search forms like these and connecting them. I'm wondering what may have been used to create this search form but it looks like a couple of modules and not a standard view. But it is possible that one of the experienced Drupal wizards here probably has a better idea than me of what was used and how it was tied together to the faceted search, which you can build in views. Thanks for any help and insight.

At the moment I am using just the built in search for faceted search with a module and it works nicely.